# message in webFrom c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, web

Error message in web

> Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running
>   in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the
>   ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a
>   notification from a service application.

**Mycode**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

protected void GridView2_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
      var confirmResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete thisitem??",
                                            "Confirm Delete!!",
                                            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
      if (confirmResult == DialogResult.Yes)
      {
          string terminal_id = GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
          selectTerminal();
          deleteTerminal(terminal_id);
      }
      else
      {
                // If 'No', do something here.
      }
 }
```

Comment: Did you check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928713/how-to-resolve-error-showing-a-modal-dialog-box-or-form-when-the-application-i

Comment: Is this code in a web page?  If so MessageBox is part of Windows Forms so will not work in the web - if your expecting to see it in a browser.

Answer (score -1):

var confirmResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete thisitem??",
                                            "Confirm Delete!!",
                                            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,     MessageBoxIcon.None);

try using this :)

Comment: The question is about `ASP .NET WEB FORMS` not about `Windows Forms`