# How can print server side from client app via WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, stimulsoft

When I run application on server, it prints locally via StimulSoft Print Method to a Physical thermal Printer Properly, but when I call same method from a client app from WCF, get this error:

"Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application."

```
PrinterSettings ps1 = new PrinterSettings();
ps1.PrinterName = MyPrintControler.SellerPrinterName;
stiReport.Print(false, ps1);
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928713/how-to-resolve-error-showing-a-modal-dialog-box-or-form-when-the-application-i

Comment: I saw this post, its about Message Dialog Box, so it is significant, but i want to print...

Comment: If you're running that website on IIS, try `sc config w3svc type=own type=interact` or configure the service process on the server to ["interact with the desktop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237225/allow-service-to-interact-with-desktop-in-windows) and see if that solves your immediate problem.

Comment: Problem Solved, when i used print method with 2 parameter, not with 1 parameter!!!!

Comment: @nimakhankhanizadeh: Can you share your solution?