# deploying webapp in azure devops pipeline release w powershell / json templates - error - modal dialog box is not valid

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

#Using Azure DevOps pipeline release with a powershell script and a json template file and json parameter #file.   Note-authenticating to the azure portal requires multi factor authentication (ie.authenticator on my mobile)

```
#'ERROR- >>>>> <strong>"Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in #UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly #style to display a notification from a service application."</strong>
#(Note- Bottom of logs immediately below contains this modal error.)'
    
    
    2020-11-14T20:33:38.7159389Z ##[section]Starting: WebApp_Create01
    2020-11-14T20:33:38.7499602Z ==============================================================================
    2020-11-14T20:33:38.7499865Z Task         : Azure PowerShell
    2020-11-14T20:33:38.7499927Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
    2020-11-14T20:33:38.7499981Z Version      : 3.1.28
    2020-11-14T20:33:38.7500050Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
    2020-11-14T20:33:38.7500132Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell
    2020-11-14T20:33:38.7500215Z ==============================================================================
    2020-11-14T20:33:40.5542183Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM\6.13.1\AzureRM.psd1 -Global
    2020-11-14T20:33:54.9421385Z ##[command]Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process
    2020-11-14T20:33:55.3824175Z ##[command]Disable-AzureRmContextAutosave -ErrorAction Stop
    2020-11-14T20:33:56.1766169Z ##[command]Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzXXXXXXXXXXXXXnt @processScope
    2020-11-14T20:33:57.8815316Z ##[command] Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId c27XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2 -TenantId ***
    2020-11-14T20:33:58.5484671Z ##[command]& 'C:\agent\Workfolder_CloudUiPathAgent03\_temp\939d1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2127.ps1'
    2020-11-14T20:33:58.7424214Z ##[command]Disconnect-AzureRmAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
    2020-11-14T20:33:59.1018440Z ##[command]Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
    <strong>2020-11-14T20:33:59.7603535Z ##[error]Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.</strong>
    2020-11-14T20:33:59.8133689Z ##[section]Finishing: WebApp_Create01
    <br>
    
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    
    #The immediately below is the ps1 pasted into the section for the "Inline" script.  Pipeline was #created as "Azure Powershell":
    
    
    
    Connect-AzureRmAccount -Environment AzXXXXXXXXXXXXXnt -TenantId '410XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXf1d' -Force
    Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription "c271XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX832"
    # Tried both Connect-AzureRmAccount and Login-AzureRmAccount without any success?
    #Login-AzureRmAccount -Environment AzXXXXXXXXXXXXXt | Out-Null
    #Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription "c271XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX832" | Out-Null
    
    <br>
    # Deploy App Service Plan, Web App & Deployment Slots
    $DeploymentParametersBuildVM = @{
        ResourceGroupName = 'DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXamic'
        TemplateUri       = 'https://dXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.blob.core.XXXXXcloudapi.net/blob-uXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX7/webappcreate.json'
    TemplateParameterFile = "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXapi.net/blob-uXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX7/webappcreate.parameters.json"
        Verbose           = $true
        webAppName        = 'uXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX7'
        hostingPlanName   = 'WebXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01' 
        templateSasToken  = 'mtAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXpSTQ=='
        subscriptionId = 'c271XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX832'
        name = 'uXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX7'
        location = 'UXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        serverFarmResourceGroup = 'DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXamic'
        Tenantid = '410XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXf1d'
        alwaysOn = 'off'    
        sku = 'Free'
        skuCode = 'F1'      
        workerSize = '0'
        workerSizeId = '0'
        numberOfWorkers = '1'
        currentStack = 'dotnet'
        phpVersion = 'OFF'
        appInsightValue = 'uXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXo7Insight'
        netFrameworkVersion = 'v4.0'
        azureAccountPassword  = '12XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXditto'
        accountid = 'a183XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX68fa'
        Credential = '12XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXditto'
        ServicePrincipal = '_MV_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX9~1e'
           
        
    }
    
    
    # DEPLOY
    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment @DeploymentParametersBuildVM
    
    
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    
    #webapp.parameters.json    (this is the azure webapp "parameter" json immediately below): 
    
    
        
    {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {
            "subscriptionId": {
                "value": "c271XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX832"
            },
            "name": {
                "value": "uXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX7"
            },
            "location": {
                "value": "UXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "hostingPlanName": {
                "value": "WebXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX01"
            },
            "serverFarmResourceGroup": {
                "value": "DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXic"
            },
            "alwaysOn": {
                "value": "true"
            },
            "sku": {
                "value": "Free"
            },
            "skuCode": {
                "value": "F1"
            },
            "workerSize": {
                "value": "0"
            },
            "workerSizeId": {
                "value": "0"
            },
            "numberOfWorkers": {
                "value": "1"
            },
            "currentStack": {
                "value": "dotnet"
            },
            "phpVersion": {
                "value": "OFF"
            },
            "appInsightValue": {
                "value": "uXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX7Insight"
            },
            "netFrameworkVersion": {
                "value": "v4.0"
            }
        }
    }
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    
    
    #webappacreate.json   (this is the azure webapp "template" json immediately below)
    
    
    
    {
        "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {
            "subscriptionId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "location": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "hostingPlanName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "serverFarmResourceGroup": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "alwaysOn": {
                "type": "bool"
            },
            "sku": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "skuCode": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "workerSize": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "workerSizeId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "numberOfWorkers": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "currentStack": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "phpVersion": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "appInsightValue": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "netFrameworkVersion": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "appInsightName": "[concat('microsoft.insights/components/',parameters('appInsightValue'))]"
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
                "name": "[parameters('name')]",
                "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "tags": {},
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('microsoft.insights/components/',parameters('appInsightValue'))]",
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "name": "[parameters('name')]",
                    "siteConfig": {
                        "appSettings": [
                            {
                                "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
                                "value": "[reference(variables('appInsightName'), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
                                "value": "[reference(variables('appInsightName'), '2015-05-01').ConnectionString]"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                                "value": "~2"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode",
                                "value": "default"
                            }
                        ],
                        "metadata": [
                            {
                                "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
                                "value": "[parameters('currentStack')]"
                            }
                        ],
                        "phpVersion": "[parameters('phpVersion')]",
                        "netFrameworkVersion": "[parameters('netFrameworkVersion')]",
                        "alwaysOn": "[parameters('alwaysOn')]"
                    },
                    "serverFarmId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourcegroups/', parameters('serverFarmResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
                    "clientAffinityEnabled": true
                }
            },
            {
                "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
                "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
                "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "kind": "",
                "tags": {},
                "dependsOn": [],
                "properties": {
                    "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
                    "workerSize": "[parameters('workerSize')]",
                    "workerSizeId": "[parameters('workerSizeId')]",
                    "numberOfWorkers": "[parameters('numberOfWorkers')]"
                },
                "sku": {
                    "Tier": "[parameters('sku')]",
                    "Name": "[parameters('skuCode')]"
                }
            },
            {
                "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
                "name": "[parameters('appInsightValue')]",
                "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "tags": {},
                "properties": {
                    "ApplicationId": "[parameters('name')]",
                    "Request_Source": "IbizaWebAppExtensionCreate"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it seems you need to set the options of `MessageBox.Show` to either `ServiceNotification` or `DefaultDesktopOnly`. You can try the workaround provided in this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928713/how-to-resolve-error-showing-a-modal-dialog-box-or-form-when-the-application-i): adding [MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxoptions(v=vs.80).aspx)

```
MessageBox.Show(msg, "Print Error", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error,     
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification);
```

But, MessageBox is for use within windows (as opposed to web) applications. It would attempt to open a message box on the server. Here is a [ticket](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/438125/Showing-a-modal-dialog-box-or-form-when-the-applic) you can refer to.

Comment: Thank You.  Please see my solution that a MSFT pipeline SME provided above

Answer (score 0):

Found out that no authentication was required for azure devops pipeline hence no login or connect is required.  This got rid of the popup (modal error).

Next I checked with the azure devops person and he said to not use powershell in the pipeline.

He recommended "Azure Resource Group Deployment" option for the pipeline release.  This does not require any initiation script but just a json template and a json parameter.

Thank You.